# In TV script writing, how to format complex newscast?

Tags: screenwriting

I'm writing a spec script where a TV newscast is supposed to appear on the screen for a couple of minutes.

It starts with the anchor speaking from the desk about a trial that's going on. Then it cuts to some highlights of the courtroom with the anchor doing a voice over. Then it cuts to recorded video of one of the attorneys giving a statement to the press outside of the courthouse. Then it cuts back to the anchor at the desk to give her final words on the story.

Then, this newscast is supposed to segue to the next scene where a character is sitting at a diner and the newscast is playing on a TV (the character is not necessarily paying attention to it).

How would I go about formatting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be to treat it as if you are writing that TV footage as a standalone script, with each cut as a separate scene, then add the extra identifiers and camera directions when you embed it into the larger script.

For the courtroom scene, depending on how you've formatted the rest, I'm guessing something like:

COURTROOM INTERIOR

Muted footage of lawyer speaking.

Anchor (voiceover): The prosecution asserted...

-cut-

Muted footage of lawyer speaking.

Anchor (voiceover): The defence argued...

-cut-

Muted footage of judge speaking.

Anchor (voiceover): The judge ruled....

-cut-

COURTROOM EXTERIOR

Comment: Thanks. How would you go about formatting the highlights in the court room?